# getting similar images by tag , but filtering images with certain category

Tags: php, mysql

i have 3 tables

images

```
    id , name 
    1  , abc
```

image_tags

```
    id , image_id , tag
    1  , 1345     , football
    2  , 1345     , sport
    3  , 1666     , football
```

image_categories

```
    id , image_id , cat

    1  , 1345     , 7
    2  , 1345     , 3
    3  , 1666     , 8
```

in my query , i have a array of tags and i want to get similar images

it's easy ( i just wrote this pleas don't mention the syntax errors )

```
select distinct(image_tags.image_id) , images.* from 
image_tags join images on image_tags.image_id = images.id 
where image_tags.tag IN (implode(',' , $tag_Array )) limit 10
```

but here's the tricky part
i don't want the images with category  3 ! 
how can i filter images with category 3 in the same query ?

Comment: DISTINCT is not a function. It's simply an option within the SELECT clause, so DISTINCT(image_tags.image_id) means nothing.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>`JOIN` that table `image_categories` then you can filter by category `cat`:</strike>

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  it.image_id, 
  i.* 
FROM image_tags AS it
INNER JOIN images           AS i ON it.image_id = i.id 
INNER JOIN image_categories AS c ON c.image_id  = i.id
WHERE it.tag IN (implode(',' , $tag_Array )) 
  AND c.cat <> 3
LIMIT 10;
```

See it in action here:

- [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2590f/2)

---

### Update

Use the `NOT IN` predicate or `LEFT JOIN`:

```
Select distinct 
  it.image_id,
  i.* 
from image_tags AS it
INNER JOIN images           AS i ON it.image_id = i.id 
WHERE it.tag IN (implode(',' , $tag_Array ))
  AND it.image_id NOT IN(SELECT image_id 
                         FROM image_categories
                         WHERE image_id <> 3
                           AND image_id IS NOT NULL)
  limit 10;
```

See it in action here:

- [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2590f/5)

Comment: thank you but i dont want image id `1345` in the result cuz it is in the category 3 !